# How we can know the bounds for the factorial $n!$

Tags: factorial, upper-lower-bounds

If we know that there exist a positive integer $n$ in an interval $[a,b]$. Here $a,b$ are real numbers. How we can know the bounds for the factorial $n!$.

Comment: What's wrong with $b!$?

Comment: @Arthur: Here $a,b$ are real numbers.

Comment: And with $\lfloor a\rfloor!$ and $\lceil b\rceil!\,$?

Comment: @Gabe Yes you can: the other natural idea $a\cdot (a-1)\cdot \ldots$ is sometimes better (say $a=5.8$, then $\Gamma(6.8)<497$ whereas $5.8\times 4.8\times\ldots>533$).

Comment: Ah yes, I didn’t notice that n was an integer. Then the bound would simply be ceil(a)! And floor(b)! then, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two natural things to say:

- It's between $\Gamma(a+1)$ and $\Gamma(b+1)$ where $\Gamma$ is [defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).
- It's between $a\cdot (a-1)\cdot\ldots\, $ (stop when you reach a factor that is less than $2$) and $b\cdot (b-1)\cdot\ldots\, $ (same).

In fact it seems$^{\color{blue}{\left[\underline{\text{reference needed}}\right]}^{\star}}$ that $\Gamma(x+1)$ is always less than or equal to $x\times (x-1)\times\ldots$, meaning that the tightest couple of bounds would be $$a\cdot(a-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot (a-\lfloor a\rfloor+1)<n!<\Gamma(b+1)$$

---

$^\star$Edit: Peter Foreman proved the inequality $\Gamma(x+1)\leq \prod_{k=0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}(x-k)$ in the comments below.

Comment: Using the recursive defintion of $\Gamma(x+1)$ we have$$\Gamma(x+1)=\Gamma(x-\lfloor x\rfloor+1)\prod_{k=0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}(x-k)$$but, as $1\le x-\lfloor x\rfloor+1\lt2$, we have $0.885603\lt\Gamma(x-\lfloor x\rfloor+1)\le1$ which implies that$$\Gamma(x+1)\le\prod_{k=0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}(x-k)$$

Comment: @PeterForeman Nice. I'll include this in the body of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Aurnaud Mortier said , I think the answer is that $\lceil a \rceil !\le n! \le \lfloor b \rfloor ! $ , where $\lceil a  \rceil $ is the ceiling function of $a$ and $\lfloor b \rfloor$ is the floor function of b.  If $a$ and $b$ are integers, it's obvious why that is. If one of them is a real number, you can only have a factorial of a natural number, and you check the one imediatly above or down.

This is slighty more precise than between $a⋅(a−1)\cdot{...}$  and $b⋅(b−1)\cdot{...}$ ,
at least if you are looking for factorial for naturals.
If you want to "extend" it to the reals, the gama function solution is the right one, this is for n as a positive integer.

*Edit

This is tighter than other solutions because for all $x$:

$\lfloor x  \rfloor ! \le Γ(x+1)$